How to download image and show it on screen from firebase storage
I would like to show an image which was downloaded from firebase storage ons screen.
export const getMyImage = async (userId) => {
  try {
    if (!userId) {
      throw new Error("Invalid userId");
    }

    // ストレージの参照を取得
    const userDocRef = ref(storage, `${userId}/image`);

    // 画像のダウンロードURLを取得
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(userDocRef);
    console.log("TEST", downloadURL);
    // This can be downloaded directly:
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = (event) => {
      const blob = xhr.response;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', downloadURL);
    xhr.send()

    // URLを返す
    return downloadURL;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("getMyImage: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

so far,I can get url like below

so all i want to do is to show the image on screen

const Main = () => {
  const [otherRiders, setOtherRiders] = useState([]);

  const dbref = ref(database); //取得したいデータのパスを指定
  const [routeInfo, setRouteInfo] = useState({ origin: "", destination: "" });
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // useNavigationフックを使用してnavigationオブジェクトを取得
  const route = useRoute();
  const user_id = route.params?.user_id;
  const [myCurrentLocation, setMyCurrentLocation] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  });
  const [myDestination, setMyDestination] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  });
  const [myOrigin, setMyOrigin] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  });
  // DB を取得している

  const [isMapReady, setIsMapReady] = useState(false);
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  let [iconImage, setImageUri] = useState(null);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled((previousState) => !previousState);
//   iconImage = require('../../assets/kurumi.jpg');

  const myDestinationIcon = require("../../assets/flag.png");
  const myOriginIcon = require("../../assets/start.png");

  // requestLocationPermission();
  useEffect(() => {
    requestLocationPermission(
      setMyCurrentLocation,
      user_id,
      myCurrentLocation,
      setIsMapReady,
      
    );
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchMyUserData = await getMyUserData(user_id);
        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",fetchMyUserData)
        const fetchMyImage = await getMyImage(user_id);
        console.log("fetchMyImage",fetchMyImage)       
        setImageUri(fetchMyImage);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching image: ", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
    const childAddedListener = onChildAdded(dbref, function (snapshot) {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      setOtherRiders(data);
    });

    return () => {
      // コンポーネントがアンマウントされたときにイベントリスナーを解除する
      childAddedListener();
    };
  }, []);

  return isMapReady ? ( // マップが準備完了したら表示
    <ScrollView style={styles.Wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: myCurrentLocation.latitude,
            longitude: myCurrentLocation.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        >
            <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: myCurrentLocation.latitude,
                    longitude: myCurrentLocation.longitude,
                }}
            >
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={iconImage} />
          </Marker>
          
          {Array.isArray(otherRiders) && otherRiders.length > 0
            ? otherRiders.map((rider, index) => {
                console.log("rider", rider);
                let diferLat =
                  Math.abs(myCurrentLocation.latitude - rider.latitude) < 1;
                let diferLot =
                  Math.abs(myCurrentLocation.longitude - rider.longitude) < 1;
                // if(diferLat && diferLot){
                //     Alert.alert("手を振りましょう")
                // }
                return (
                  <Marker
                    key={index} // ここで一意のキーを提供する
                    coordinate={{
                      latitude: rider.latitude,
                      longitude: rider.longitude,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Image style={styles.icon} source={iconImage} />
                  </Marker>
                );
              })
            : null}
        </MapView>
      </View>

      <View>
        <Button
          title="ルートを検索する"
          onPress={() => fetchRoute(setMyOrigin, setMyDestination, routeInfo)}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button title="戻る" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Top")} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.waitContainer}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      <Text style={styles.waitText}>少々お待ちください...</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

i home to insert the image i downloaded into iconImage.
            <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: myCurrentLocation.latitude,
                    longitude: myCurrentLocation.longitude,
                }}
            >
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={iconImage} />
          </Marker>

Could you please provide some information how does it work?
Thank you for reading here and hope to give me your hands.

When using Firebase Storage, the typical use pattern is:

upload image to Storage
get its "download URL"
store the download URL (a string) as data in a database along with other data elements

for example, if you are uploading a photo as a product's display image, get the download URL and store it in the database as a string value along with the rest of the product's description (name, price, size, weight, photoURL, etc....)



Later, when a user is browsing the database (e.g. searching for products), when they get the data for a product they would get the photoURL image and use that URL in an image tag:
<Image source={productData.photoURL} />


THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
When i use object with url key instead of direct,It works!<Image style={styles.icon} source={{ uri: iconImage }} />

Oh, I missed that you were using React-Native.  So yes...that is how you'd have to call the  for React-Native.  Other libraries offer their own  that are configured differently.
